# $dateToString and $subString not showing proper date

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

```
db.checkins.aggregate
 ([{'$match':{"checkinData.time":
                    {"$gt":ISODate("2017-08-31T18:30:00.000Z"),
                    "$lte":ISODate("2017-08-31T20:00:00.000Z")}}},

  {"$project":{'dte': {"$dateToString": 
                             {format: "%Y-%m-%d", date:"$checkinData.time"}
                      }
              }}

])
```

Data  return from Data Base it perfectly good it means all data return of **next date (2017/09/01).**
but problem is that **value of field 'dte' are showing previous date (2017-08-31)**

> **but I have  to show value of 'dte' is  next date  (2017-09-01).**

I have used **$dateToString** and  **$subString**

```
{"$project":{"dte":{"$substr":["$checkinData.time",0,10]},
```

it also same return **2017-08-31**

> Is there any method or query in mongoDB to show next date for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this script.

```
  {"$project":{ 'dte': { "$dateToString": { format: "%Y-%m-%d", 
                        date:{ $add: [ "$checkinData.time", 
                                { $subtract: [ new Date( "1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z" ), new Date( "1970-01-01T00:00:00.000" ) ] } // Time Offset 
                                ] } } } } }
```

I just added time zone difference to your date. I calculated the time offset like this.

```
$subtract: [ new Date( "1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z" ), new Date( "1970-01-01T00:00:00.000" ) ]
```